# Get Facebook 'share/post' event for share dialog

Tags: javascript, facebook, popup, facebook-events

My site allows each user to share a link, say http://www.my-site.com, on facebook.

I'd like to count the number of times each user shared my url, as well as the date of the last share. This would have been pretty easy given one would have used the FB SDK (excuse the coffeescript):

```
link = "my-site.com"

FB.ui
    method: "feed"
    link: link
    from: from
  , (response) ->
    unless response is null or response is undefined
      $.ajax
        dataType: "json"
        data: response
        url: some-url
        success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
          // Do stuff
```

I could have even let myself get more create and use one of facebook's event subscriptions, such as:

```
FB.Event.subscribe "message.send", message_send_callback
```

However, as far as I know, none of the dialogs offered by FB.ui() allows the user to choose which group/wall/friend he would like to post to, which is mandatory as far as I'm concerned. Fortunately, the non-SDK share dialog DOES allow for exactly that, but presents a bigger challenge when it comes to getting the post event and the response, as it forces me to add an onload event listener to the popup window (`var popup = window.open(...); popup.addEventListener...`), and then add another event listener to the post event, which is of course challenging because the popup opens another domain, facebook's, which I have no control over.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to accomplish? Am I missing a FB.ui() dialog that enables the user to choose where to post? If not - is there a way to get the event and response for the share dialog?

Comment: No, I think there is no way as of now to use the Share dialog with FB.ui, or get it to give any feedback. What you could try is using the feed dialog with the `to` parameter – if you are willing to put a dialog of your own in front of it that lets the user chose a post target. Although that will limit you to their friends and pages you might be able to suggest – if the latter should be user specific, you will have to ask for permission to read their likes etc.

Comment: @CBroe, that's actually what I ended up doing - I'm using the 'from' and 'to' properties, as well as other, irrelevant techniques, to get all affiliated fb entities. If you add it as an answer I'll mark it as the right one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, I think there is no way as of now to use the Share dialog with FB.ui, or get it to give any feedback.

What you could try is using the feed dialog with the `to` parameter – if you are willing to put a dialog of your own in front of it that lets the user chose a post target.

Although that will limit you to their friends and pages you might be able to suggest – if the latter should be user specific, you will have to ask for permission to read their likes etc.